# Using perl REST::Application to parse url query string

Tags: perl, rest, url

I'm using perl's `REST::Application` to generate html dynamically on my server with cgi script that looks somewhat like:

```
my $url_map = { 
            qr|^/?$| => {
                    GET => \&get_help,
            },
            qr|^/builders/?$| => {
                    GET => \&get_builders,
            },
    };
```

I would like to add support for query strings. For example, if the url would be `www.example.com/query?param1=a&param2=b` I would like to be able to call a procedure with those values as parameters. However, If only one of the parameters is given, it should be supported as well.

Answer (score -1):

Possible solution could be using `HTML::Entities` and `CGI`:

Add relevant modules:

```
use CGI;
use HTML::Entities;
```

Add prpoer line to `$url_map`:

```
qr|^/query(.*)| => {
                    GET => \&get_query,
            }
```

And implement:

```
sub get_uploads {
    $rest->header(-type => "text/plain, charset=utf8");
    my $cgi = CGI->new;
    my %params = map { $_ => HTML::Entities::encode(join("; ", split("\0", $cgi->Vars->{$_}))) } $cgi->param;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

At this stage `%params` will hold the query string.
For example, if I used the `url` in the question, `%params` would be:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'param1' => 'a',
      'param2' => 'b'
    };
```

Comment: I don't think that is a good idea to promote use of `CGI.pm`.

Comment: @darch Can you elaborate? Can you suggest a better solution?

Comment: I could, but I'll let SawyerX do it:  https://youtu.be/jKOqtRMT85s .  As for alternatives, I'd love to offer one -- but I just found that `REST::Application` is based on `CGI`, so the question is moot.

Comment: @darch But the question specifically refers to REST::Application, so you could have just skipped it